# Páginação Bootstrap 4

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, paginação

Buenas pessoal,

Estou com uma duvida relativamente simples, mas não achei nada na internet que me responda.

Eu estou implementando uma páginação com o bootstrap 4:
https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/pagination/

Porém o meu conteúdo ele esta estático no HTML, não vem de banco de json e etc.
Eu preciso implementar uma paginação em um conteúdo estático, porém não sei como a paginação do bootstrap funciona.
No site do bootstrap  não achei nenhum exemplo completo com a paginação funcionando.

Queria saber como deve ficar a estrutura html para esconder os itens e fazer eles aparecerem conforme o usuário clica na páginação 1, 2, 3 e assim por diante.

Alguém tem alguma ideia?

Abraço!

Answer (score 3):

Não sei se entendi bem a pergunta mas vamos lá,

o Bootstrap obedece a orientação das classes: "Page navigation", "pagination", "page-item" e "page-link". Um exemplo pode ser encontrado no seguinte link do site Bootstrap:

[Site Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com.br/v4/components/pagination/)

```
<nav aria-label="Page navigation">
<ul class="pagination">
<li class="page-item">
  <a class="page-link" href="#" aria-label="Previous">
    <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
</li>
<li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">1</a></li>
<li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">2</a></li>
<li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">3</a></li>
<li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">4</a></li>
<li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">5</a></li>
<li class="page-item">
  <a class="page-link" href="#" aria-label="Next">
    <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

Agora basta substituir o # em href="#" pelo link estático que desejar.

Acredito que seja isto que deseja fazer. em exemplo:

```
<li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="AQUI FICA O CAMINHO PARA PÁGINA ESTÁTICA">1</a></li>
```

espero ter ajudado, abraços!

Comment: Gabriel, a sua reposta responde em partes a minha pergunta, mas responde. 
A minha ideia era fazer a troca de página sem mudar a url. Eu resolvi isso de uma outra forma, mas a sua resposta me ajudou sim.

Comment: da um up pra mim então =) fico feliz! vlw